# req.isAuthenticated() never evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I'm trying to implement user authentication as below:

```
userRouter.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const { _id, username } = req.user;
        const token = signToken(_id);
        res.cookie("access_token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: true });
        res.status(200).json({ isAuthenticated: true, user: { username } });
    }
});
```

But to be able to add some custom messages I'm using the alternative below:

```
userRouter.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local',{ session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            const { _id, username } = req.user;
            const token = signToken(_id);
            res.cookie("access_token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: true });
            res.status(200).json({ isAuthenticated: true, user: { username } });
        }
        if (err) return next(err)
        if (info)
            res.status(400).json({ message: { msgBody: info.message, msgError: true } });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

However, in the second alternative, it seems like `req.isAuthenticated()` is never evaluated to true.

Can anyone help me understand why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The passport docs say "Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response." (http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)

With the follow code as an example:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

I wonder if it says you are not authenticated because you need to call the login method?

Comment: Really difficult as to say and debug as I'm not really getting any errors anywhere in the code :(

Comment: Have you tried calling req.logIn like the example and testing isAuthenticated in the callback for that?